# Leave if loop inside while loop

Tags: loops, powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell script that is constantly checking the status of a game server that I'm running and, depending on the states of certain exe's and variables, certain things will happen.  The way I have this constructed is, first I have a timer start and I have a while loop that runs up until the timer hits 280 seconds. Within this while loop there are a series of if than else statements that look at all of the aforementioned variable and states of exe's and then they execute different things.  What I'd like is that when it gets to the end of a condition (if the exe is not found and the server status is 0), then email me about that and then go back to the beginning of the entire `while` loop and keep looping and checking the status of the server.

Here is the script right now in:

```
//$serverStatus = 1 means servers up, 0 means down, 3 means crashed
$timeout = new-timespan -Seconds 280
$sw = [diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()
while ($sw.elapsed -lt $timeout){
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

    if (((get-process $process -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq $Null) -And ($serverStatus -eq "1")) {
        #Server is down and email
        "0" > "D:\Ark Scripts\serverStatus.txt"
        Write-Host "it's down - email"
        sendMail -sendTo "my email" -emailBody "Ark Server is down."

    } elseif (((get-process $process -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq $Null) -And ($serverStatus -eq "0")) {
        #Server is down and we are aware
        Write-Host "it's down - we know"
    } elseIf (((get-process $process -ea SilentlyContinue) -ne $Null) -And ($serverStatus -eq "0")) {
        #Server is up and email
        "1" > "D:\Ark Scripts\serverStatus.txt"
        Write-Host "it's up - email"
        sendMail -sendTo "my email" -emailBody "Ark Server is back up."
    } elseif ($serverStatus -eq "3") {
        Send-RCON "listplayers" > "D:\Ark Scripts\RCONlog.txt"

        $log = Get-Content "D:\Ark Scripts\RCONlog.txt"

        if ($log -eq "Authentication failed!") {
            Write-Host "crashed and we know"
        } else {
           "1" > "D:\Ark Scripts\serverStatus.txt"
           Write-Host "Back up"
        }
    } else {
        #Checks RCON connection for crashes and sends crash email if connection fails.
        Send-RCON "listplayers" > "D:\Ark Scripts\RCONlog.txt"

        $log = Get-Content "D:\Ark Scripts\RCONlog.txt"

        if ($log -eq "Authentication failed!") {
            Write-Host "crashed"
            "3" > "D:\Ark Scripts\serverStatus.txt"
            sendMail -sendTo "my email" -emailBody "Ark Server has crashed."
            return
        } else {
            "1" > "D:\Ark Scripts\serverStatus.txt"
            Write-Host "it's up"
        }
    }
}

Exit-PSSession
```

I just want this while loop to keep running every 10 seconds to check the state of the variables and whether the exe is found and constantly cycle.

Comment: "loop back to beginning of while loop." = `continue`

Comment: You sir need to be introduced to `Switch`. `Get-Help about_switch` quite literally says for it's short description "Explains how to use a switch to handle multiple If statements."

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I tried using continue, but that doesnt work either. I put continue in the part where the exe found and the serverStatus is 0. it sets that variable to 1 and then emails me but when it gets back to the top it goes back to the exe is found and serverStatus is 0 part when it should be going to exe is found and serverStatus is 1. it seems like its not checking the parameters again but just running the same chunk of code over and over.

Comment: Are you doing something like `$serverStatus = 0` to check if the value of `$serverStatus` is `0`? That won't work. This will be much easier if you post the actual code you're using

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I have edited the post and pasted the actual code I have made

Comment: You might be updating the `serverstatus.txt` file, but you never actually update `$serverStatus` variable - if it's value is `0` and you restart the loop, the value is still `0` and the same `if` block is triggered. You must update the variable with `Get-Content` or compare directly against the txt file: `${D:\Ark Scripts\serverStatus.txt} -eq 0`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen oh duh. now I feel dumb.  Thank you so much for the help it's working exactly how I'd like it to now

Answer (score 0):

This wont work, script will never go into the section "#Server is up and email will never"

```
} elseif (((get-process $process -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq $Null) -And ($serverStatus -eq "0")) {
    #Server is down and we are aware
    Write-Host "it's down - we know"
} elseIf (((get-process $process -ea SilentlyContinue) -ne $Null) -And ($serverStatus -eq "0")) {
    #Server is up and email
```

You should nest your if statements to get a clear picture of what your doing